# FMX like Animations in VCL

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, vcl

I want to resize a panels width from 300 to 0 as smooth as possible.

In Firemonkey you could use `Panel1.AnimateFloat('Width', 0)`.

What i am doing currently is:

```
while Panel1.Width > 0 do
begin
   Panel1.Width := Panel1.Width - 1;
   Application.ProcessMessages;
end;
```

But i think that is not the right way to do this.

Maybe a timer is the right way to do it? But i don't want to create a timer for every animation.

Comment: What's wrong with using a timer? Surely better than ProcessMessages. Naturally you don't write the code from scratch every time. Encapsulate oit. Personally I might opt for a thread to produce the pulse. But a timer is fine too.

Comment: Also, your way you can't control the "animation" speed. The "transition" will be as fast as possible according the client cpu/gpu power.

Comment: I agree with both of you guys.

But maybe this is the way to go:
http://delphi.about.com/od/delphi-tips-2011/qt/hide-slide-fade-away-controls-delphi-form.htm

Comment: Yes, that's a good approach too

Comment: I don't know about FireMonkey, but the "problem" with the `AnimateWindow` command is the main thread is blocked for the entire animation time. Nevertheless, that's what I do on a kiosk application and it's working very fine and looks acceptable.

Comment: I would just look at the animator code of the FMX animators an rebuild it to use for any object - not limited to FMX. btw: the FMX animation uses a simple timer for the animations

Comment: Foregoing the animation rate requirements, there's the problem of pixel granularity and the cost of aligning child components in each transitional step over time. FMX's subpixel rasterization is obviously preferred. Animating viewports in OpenGL also suffers from pixel granularity.